# Spring Kafka consumer Gives an error " cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am trying to consume a JSON object using spring kafka. And the json object that the Consumer reads is like below.

```
{
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "....",
        "type": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "....",
              "type": "...."
            },
            {
              "default": null,
              "name": "........",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "items": ".....",
                  "type": "...."
                }
              ]
            },
          ],
          "name": ".....",
          "type": "...."
        }
      },
      {
        "name": ".....",
        "type": {
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": ".....",
              "type": "....."
            },
            {
              "name": ".....",
              "type": "......"
            },
            {
              "name": ".....",
              "type": "....."
            }
          ],
          "name": ".....",
          "type": "....."
        }
      },
      {
        "name": ".....",
        "type": {
          "fields": [],
          "name": ".....",
        }
      }
    ],
    "name": "....",
    "type": "....."
  }
```

When I try to deserialize this object it gives me an error
"  cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)"

This is my code so far.

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaStreamReaderConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Payload> consumerFactory(){
        Map<String,Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "groupId");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Payload.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Payload> kafkaListener(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

this is the Object class

```
public class Payload {
    private List<JsonNode> fields;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Payload(List<JsonNode> fields, String name, String type) {
        this.fields = fields;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<JsonNode> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    public void setFields(List<JsonNode> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need a default constructor or you need to mark your existing one as `@JsonCreator` and also mark constructor parameters with `@JsonProperty("paramName")`.